# Code runs fine with WinDbg but weird without it

Tags: c++, mfc, windbg

I am debugging an issue with WinDbg which I can consistently produce. The problem is when I run the executable with WinDbg to debug it, the issue can't be reproduced. What could be the reason?

Here is the code the behaves differently:

```
CWnd* pWnd = GetDlgItem(IDOKCANCEL);
if(pWnd)
{
    CString sOK;
    sOK.LoadString(IDS_OK);
    pWnd->SetWindowText(sOK);
}
```

Here the button text is updated properly when I run with WinDbg but it is not updated when I run it normally (which is the bug).

**Update**

Like I said in comments, the issue is not with the code above because it's doesn't even get called. The operation is done in a worker thread which sends update messages to this dialog. The final message that executes the above code is never send do it so the above code is never executed.

Why the worker thread doesn't send this message is interesting. It ges locked on a critical section while opening a database. WinDbg tells me that the main thread is the owner of that critical section but I can't see from call stack or any other way where does it failed to unlock the critical section.

What complicates the problem is that it works fine if I run it with debugger. I added log output but it also starts to works fine with this change.

The only way I can catch it with a debugger is when I run it normal mode,  produce the problem, then attach the debugger and it shows me its locked on the critical section. It shows the main thread is the owner of that critical section but it not clear why it is in locked state. The critical section is simply locked and unlocked in one function and its out of there.

**Update 2**

I am using the critical section only in one file in my entire project and there in only two functions (when it opens database and recordset).

```
BOOL CADODatabase::Open(LPCTSTR lpstrConnection, LPCTSTR lpstrUserID, LPCTSTR lpstrPassword)
{
    CString database = GetSourceDatabase( lpstrConnection, NULL );

    // get the appropriate critical section based on database
    g_dbCriticalSection = GetDbCriticalSection( database );

    if( g_dbCriticalSection) 
        g_dbCriticalSection->Lock();

    HRESULT hr = S_OK;

    if(IsOpen())
        Close();

    if(wcscmp(lpstrConnection, _T("")) != 0)
        m_strConnection = lpstrConnection;

    ASSERT(!m_strConnection.IsEmpty());

    try
    {
        if(m_nConnectionTimeout != 0)
            m_pConnection->PutConnectionTimeout(m_nConnectionTimeout);
        hr = m_pConnection->Open(_bstr_t(m_strConnection), _bstr_t(lpstrUserID), _bstr_t(lpstrPassword), NULL);

        if( g_dbCriticalSection) 
            g_dbCriticalSection->Unlock();

        return hr == S_OK;
    }
    catch(_com_error &e)    
    {
        dump_com_error(e);

        if( g_dbCriticalSection) 
            g_dbCriticalSection->Unlock();

        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

The 2nd function has other visible imperfections but please ignore that, its legacy code.

```
BOOL CADORecordset::Open(_ConnectionPtr mpdb, LPCTSTR lpstrExec, int nOption)
{   
    BSTR bstrConnString;
    m_pConnection->get_ConnectionString(&bstrConnString);
    CString database = GetSourceDatabase( bstrConnString, m_pConnection );

    g_dbCriticalSection = GetDbCriticalSection( database );

    if( g_dbCriticalSection) 
        g_dbCriticalSection->Lock();

    Close();

    if(wcscmp(lpstrExec, _T("")) != 0)
        m_strQuery = lpstrExec;

    ASSERT(!m_strQuery.IsEmpty());

    if(m_pConnection == NULL)
        m_pConnection = mpdb;

    m_strQuery.TrimLeft();
    BOOL bIsSelect = m_strQuery.Mid(0, _tcslen(_T("Select "))).CompareNoCase(_T("select ")) == 0 && nOption == openUnknown;

    int maxRetries = 10;
    bool bContinue = true;

    CursorTypeEnum adCursorType = adOpenStatic;
    if (!m_bSQLEngine)
    {
        // MDB Engine
        adCursorType = adOpenStatic;
        m_pConnection->CursorLocation = adUseClient;
    }
    else
    {
        // SQL Engine
        adCursorType = adOpenDynamic;
        m_pConnection->CursorLocation = adUseServer;
    }

    int currentCommandTimeout = m_pConnection->CommandTimeout;

    if( g_dbCriticalSection) 
        g_dbCriticalSection->Unlock();

    for (int iRetry = 0; (iRetry < maxRetries) && bContinue; iRetry++)
    {
        try
        {
            // we just use an auto lock object so it is unlocked automatically, it uses same 
            // critical section object.
            if( g_dbCriticalSection) 
                g_dbCriticalSection->Lock();

            int newCommandTimeout = currentCommandTimeout + 15 * iRetry;
            m_pConnection->CommandTimeout = newCommandTimeout;


            if(bIsSelect || nOption == openQuery || nOption == openUnknown)
            {

                m_pRecordset->Open((LPCTSTR)m_strQuery, _variant_t((IDispatch*)mpdb, TRUE), 
                                adCursorType, adLockOptimistic, adCmdUnknown);
            }
            else if(nOption == openTable)
            {
                m_pRecordset->Open((LPCTSTR)m_strQuery, _variant_t((IDispatch*)mpdb, TRUE), 
                            adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic, adCmdTable);
            }
            else if(nOption == openStoredProc)
            {
                m_pCmd->ActiveConnection = mpdb;
                m_pCmd->CommandText = _bstr_t(m_strQuery);
                m_pCmd->CommandType = adCmdStoredProc;

                m_pRecordset = m_pCmd->Execute(NULL, NULL, adCmdText);
            }
            else
            {
                TRACE( _T("Unknown parameter. %d"), nOption);

                if( g_dbCriticalSection) 
                    g_dbCriticalSection->Unlock();

                return FALSE;
            }

            if( g_dbCriticalSection) 
                g_dbCriticalSection->Unlock();

            bContinue = false;
        }
        catch(_com_error &e)
        {
            if( g_dbCriticalSection) 
                g_dbCriticalSection->Unlock();

            dump_com_error_without_exception(e, _T("Open"));

            // retry Query timeout

            CString szDescription;
            _bstr_t bstrDescription(e.Description());
            szDescription.Format( _T("%s"), (LPCTSTR)bstrDescription);

            if ((szDescription.Find(_T("Query timeout expired")) == -1) || (iRetry == maxRetries - 1))
            {
                m_pConnection->CommandTimeout = currentCommandTimeout;
                throw CADOException(e.Error(), e.Description());
            }
            Sleep (1000);
            bContinue = true;
        }

    }

    m_pConnection->CommandTimeout = currentCommandTimeout;

    return m_pRecordset != NULL && m_pRecordset->GetState()!= adStateClosed;
}
```

For the sake of completeness, the above calls this function:

```
static CCriticalSection* GetDbCriticalSection(const CString& database)
{
  // For now we only care about one database and its corresponding critical section
    if (database.CompareNoCase( _T("Alr") ) == 0)
        return &g_csAlrDb; // g_csAlrDb is defined static global in this file
    else
        return 0;

}
```

The Open() function gets called for various databases, I am only locking guarding access to one database. As you can see there is corresponding lock/unlocks so not sure how does code comes up of these functions leave th critical section locked. Could it be because of [MFC issue](http://www.flounder.com/avoid_mfc_syncrhonization.htm)?

Comment: Heavily smells like you're calling undifined behavior (may be elsewhere).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I am investigating/exploring other factors but this is the place where button text gets updated. I am wondering what could be the reason at least it runs fine with WinDbg? It's essentially same environment! Why different results?

Comment: Does this code run on the same thread that created the dialog?

Comment: Debuggers can do some interesting things in their own rights. I've seen sockets and file IO not work while using GDB, but work fine outside. I've seen buffer overflows (Which I suspect is padding added by valgrind. gdb. etc) that don't occur to a much more distant part of the program than expected.

Comment: As others have said, launching under a debugger can change program behaviour, especially when invoking undefined behaviour. The biggest cause for this sort of thing is the [debug heap](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130103-00/?p=5653).
As a first step, try turning off the debug heap, or launch the program without the debugger _then_ attach a debugger. If that allows you to reproduce the bug while under the debugger, set a breakpoint where things aren't working and figure out how the program got into that state.

Comment: <eliminating the obvious>Are you sure this is not just a refresh issue? Did you verify the windowtext using Spy++ for instance? </eliminating the obvious>

Comment: @IInspectable Yes.

Comment: Without the debugger, can you try clicking and right-clicking, minimizing etc. the application in the Windows task bar? It might be a message pump issue which does not occur when you switch between windows (i.e. the Debugger and your App).

Comment: Imagine that you don't have debugger at all. Investigate the problem using OutputDebugString/TRACE and DbgView.

Comment: @IInspectable I didn't quite get your question too well.Turns out this dialog is created a seperate worker thread. Also I don't think its a refresh issue, its a modal dialog though so I can't minimize/maximize. I did  bring other windows on top and behaviour is same.

Comment: A modal dialog created on a different thread from the owning windows's thread is a bug. This cannot be made to work. Still, you didn't answer the question I asked: Is the code in your question run on the same thread that created the dialog?

Comment: @IInspectable The way it is this dialog is created in worker thread than worker thread `SendMessage()` to this modal class to make updates there.The code I posted is in the handler when it receives the final finish message. It's legacy code, I am trying to make sense out of it.

Comment: That should be trivially easy to verify: Set a breakpoint in the dialog class' c'tor, switch to the *Threads* view in Visual Studio, take not of the thread ID. Set a breakpoint in the code in your question. Compare the current thread's ID with the thread ID you previously noted.

Comment: @IInspectable If I set breakpoints, it gets into other issues but I have created log file with thread ids and I am getting a better picture. The code is in same thread that creates the dialog. The issue is the final message is not being sent to dialog, so its likely due to something else. I am close to figure it out.

Comment: @zar - you didn't answer all comments so it's not clear if you still need to resolve this?

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers I did answer all and updated question. I had discovered it has to do with a lock and I should be able to figure it out but that turn out that lock behavior itself is very tricky and is the main issue. So yes I am still looking for answer.

Comment: Can you post the function locking/unlocking the CS?

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers I updated post with code of two functions which is the only place I use the critical section in whole project.

Comment: From that code, it's not guaranteed that the CS gets unlocked. If opening the connection throws any other error than `_com_error`, you will not find it in the loggings and it will not get unlocked.

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers Good point but I have tried that as well and problem is still there. This file is part of a dll, could that play anything with it? I say this because I tried to use raw Win32 critical section and that doesn't work at all because it has to be initialized (in `dllmain()`) which I noticed gets called multiple times.

Comment: <quote>Whenever you create a new thread, your DLL will get DllMain call with DLL_THREAD_ATTACH reason as second argument! This is by design and provide you a chance to make some thread based initialization in your DLL</quote>

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers I have since switched to named mutex which I create in exe and use in dll just to be sure it's not due to an unknown issue with dll and the problem persists.

Comment: Sorry but I have nothing else to suggest other than making sure that the CS get's unlocked by using a finally block.

Answer (score -1):

In my case, most of the time, when C++ software behaves different between debug and release versions, it's because of uninitialized variables, different libraries linked, or compiler optimizations backfiring.

To trace the bug, try evaluating variables and function return values, i.e. `LoadString`, for example with `AfxMessageBox()`.

Comment: It is obvious from the little information in the question, that the error cannot be due to uninitialized variables. All variables in the code **are** visibly initialized. Sorry, this answer is not useful.

Comment: As is your comment.

Comment: @Illnspectable: IDS_OK may come from a linked dll with a different value than in the linking program. If you try to debug such cases, don't presume anything!

Comment: If there is no string resource with ID `IDS_OK`, then that doesn't make `sOK` uninitialized ex post facto. Are you sure you understand basic language concepts? Besides, the OP never claimed a difference between running different configurations. They are running the **same** configuration, with and without a debugger attached. Again, this proposed answer is not at all useful. (P.S.: Your previous comment should really be flagged as *"rude and offensive"*. However, I'll leave it in place, in case a future customer is interested to find out about your understanding of professional communication.)

Comment: Maybe it was rude, but also true, sorry for that. But it was not half as rude as the allegation of me not understanding basic language concepts. And it was not only this time, I found your comment all too nitpickerish. It's like I would tell you, you don't know about language concepts because, configurations and debugger are completely different things. A bit more tolerance and benevolence would be appropriate here, where people try to help other people in their spare time -- even if they are not as perfect as you.